# Invalid Name in Augmentation + Cannot Find its Corresponding Type Declarations

Tags: typescript, import, module, png, type-declaration

I have a react project structured like this:

```
--client/
----index.tsx
----components/
--public
----/images
--server
----...server stuff
--types
----bunch a folders
----declaration.d.ts
----index.ts
--tsconfig.json
--webpack.config.js
```

In my front-end code, I import a logo like this:

```
import logo1 from "../../../../public/images/logo1.png";
import logo2 from "../../../../public/images/logo2.svg";
```

And I get the following error:

```
Cannot find module '../../public/images/logo1.png' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

I looked it up and saw many answers suggesting that I declare the module in a declaration.d.ts file, so I made that in my types/ folder:

```
declare module "*.png" {
    const string: any;
    export default string;
}
declare module "*.svg";
```

Still the same error. I moved this logic to types/index.ts to see what would happen and now I get the same error as above but also the new code has this error:

```
Invalid module name in augmentation, module '*.png' cannot be found.
```

Here is my tsconfig.json file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "target": "es6",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "dist",

        // Additional
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        // "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "jsx": "react",
        "types": [
            "node",
            "react",
            "react-dom",
            "express",
            "mocha",
            "chai",
            "dotenv",
            "validator"
        ],
        "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types", "types"],
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "removeComments": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": false,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "allowJs": true
    },
    "typescript.tsdk": "node_modules/typescript/lib",
    "lib": ["es2015"],
    "exclude": ["dist", "node_modules"]
}
```

And here is webpack:

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const NodePolyfillPlugin = require("node-polyfill-webpack-plugin");

const webpackConfig = {
    entry: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "./client/index.tsx"),
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "./public/dist"),
        filename: "main.js",
    },
    devtool: "source-map",
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
                loader: "url-loader",
                options: {
                    limit: 10000,
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: "ts-loader",
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            },
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                options: {
                    presets: ["@babel/preset-react"],
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "source-map-loader",
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        fallback: {
            http: require.resolve("stream-http"),
        },
        extensions: [
            "",
            ".webpack.js",
            ".web.js",
            ".ts",
            ".tsx",
            ".js",
            ".jsx",
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            process: "process/browser",
        }),
        new NodePolyfillPlugin(),
    ],
};

module.exports = webpackConfig;
```

I cannot workaround with `const logo = require("../../../../public/images/logo1.png")` because while it does stop the error, my images don't show up on the page anymore.

The crazy thing is though that I have other imports for pngs and svgs THAT ARE WORKING in other files... it recognizes it is a `module "*.png"`. So is this perhaps something wrong with VS Code?